# new badge on category list php

Tags: php

i am having category sidebar below code

**Working Code:**

```
//Showing categories function
function getCats(){
global $db;

$q_cats = "select * from cats ORDER BY cat_name ASC";
$run_cats = mysqli_query($db, $q_cats);
while($row_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
    $cat_id = $row_cat['cat_id'];
    $cat_name = $row_cat['cat_name'];
        $q_count = "select * from messages where cat_id='$cat_id'";
        $run_count = mysqli_query($db, $q_count);
        $cat_sms_count = mysqli_num_rows($run_count);
            if($cat_sms_count < 1){
                $cat_sms_count = 0;
                }       
    echo "<a href='category.php?category=$cat_id' class='list-group-item'>$cat_name<span class='badge'>$cat_sms_count</span></a>";

    }//while row END here

        $q_tmsgs = "select * from messages";
        $run_tcount = mysqli_query($db, $q_tmsgs);
        $tsms_count = mysqli_num_rows($run_tcount);
        echo "<a href='allindb.php' class='list-group-item t-list'>Total Messages in DB<span class='badge'>$tsms_count</span></a>";

    }//Function getCats END here
```

this working fine but what i want, i want to add a new badge image next to the category name. i tried a lot but failed to do, what i think is the most relevant code.

**Please check this code:**

```
//Showing categories function
function getCats(){
global $db;

$q_cats = "select * from cats ORDER BY cat_name ASC";
$run_cats = mysqli_query($db, $q_cats);
while($row_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
    $cat_id = $row_cat['cat_id'];
    $cat_name = $row_cat['cat_name'];
        $q_count = "select * from messages where cat_id='$cat_id'";
        $run_count = mysqli_query($db, $q_count);
        $cat_sms_count = mysqli_num_rows($run_count);
        //problem area----------------------------------
                    $q_new = "select * from messages where cat_id='$cat_id' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20";
                    $run_new = mysqli_query($db, $q_new);
                    while($new = mysqli_num_rows($run_new)){
                        $newbadge = $new['cat_id'];
                        }
                        if($cat_id==$newbadge){
                            $newbadge1 = "<img src='images/mynew.gif'>";
                            }

        //--------------------------------------------              
            if($cat_sms_count < 1){
                $cat_sms_count = 0;
                }       
    echo "<a href='category.php?category=$cat_id' class='list-group-item'>$cat_name $newbadge1<span class='badge'>$cat_sms_count</span></a>";

    }//while row END here

        $q_tmsgs = "select * from messages";
        $run_tcount = mysqli_query($db, $q_tmsgs);
        $tsms_count = mysqli_num_rows($run_tcount);
        echo "<a href='allindb.php' class='list-group-item t-list'>Total Messages in DB<span class='badge'>$tsms_count</span></a>";

    }//Function getCats END here
```

Comment: What is the error/problem you have. Please provide some error/output.

Comment: Okay If I am understanding correctly your problem is you are not able to find out which category has the new message recently. So according to that you can show the `new message` badge in front of it. is it correct?

Comment: yes that i can make but my objective is i want bedge categories that belongs newest 30 msgs.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want to show "new badge" on those topics that doesnt have any messages in them. if so you got `$q_count`
Just replace the `while{}` inside with an `if{}else{}`like so:

`if($q_count == 0) {
    $newbadge1 = "<img src='images/mynew.gif'>";
    } else {
    $newbadge1 = ''; 
    }`

The problem is that you are doing another query that is returning empty array, and therefore you are getting badges on topics that has got messages. So either remove the `while{}` and replace with the if-else or you can just do a check like:
    `if(empty($new)) {
      $newbadge1 = "<img src='images/mynew.gif'>";
      } else {
      $newbadge1 = '';
      }`

Comment: you understood me wrong, my objective is to bedge categories who they are belongs to 20 newest msgs. for empty i already showing the count bedge on the right. for live development ver. u can visit amarhussain(dot)tk/smsportal to understand btr. thanks